# 'Magic number mismatch' error when loading mnist dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist

I'm trying to load the mnist digit dataset and am routinely getting this error. I'm unable to find any solutions online

This code:

```
from mnist import MNIST
m = MNIST(path)
x_train, y_train = m.load_training()
```

Yields this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mnist\loader.py", line 125, in load_training
    ims, labels = self.load(os.path.join(self.path, self.train_img_fname),
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\mnist\loader.py", line 250, in load
    raise ValueError('Magic number mismatch, expected 2049,'
ValueError: Magic number mismatch, expected 2049,got 529205256
```

I'm running python-mnist 0.7.

Comment: You're apparently running Python 3.8. Can you add the version of MNIST?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the exact same error and I fixed it by renaming the files:

- First you download the data as gzip files. The should look like this: "train-labels-idx1-ubytes.gz"
- then you need to extract these files
- then you probably get files similar to this one: "train-labels.idx1-ubyte". The error with this is that the file should be named like "train-labels-idx1-ubyte" (hyphen instead of dot).

If you rename the files like that it should work, at least that's what worked for me.

Comment: To extract the files I ran `gunzip *` when in my folder with `t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz` etc. That solved the problem for me. Thanks

Comment: I convert . to - and it works. Thanks